# How to put several Hyperlinks on the same line

Tags: html, hyperlink

I have four links that I want to have on the same line. Right now when I run the code I get them on four separate lines.

```
<a href="#" id="draw-Sweden">Sweden</a>
<div id= "flag"></div>
<a href="#2" id="draw-Norway">Norway</a>
<div id= "flagNor"></div>
<a href="#3" id="draw-Denmark">Denmark</a>
<div id= "flagDen"></div>            
<a href="#4" id="draw-Finland">Finland</a>
<div id= "flagFin"></div>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use the css float:left

Answer (score 2):

There are more possibilities. Choose one of them, which best fits you.

```
1. change `div` for `span`
2. div, a {float: left;}
3. div, a {display: inline}
```

Answer (score 0):

A div is a Block element, in order to have them on one row you must use inline elements. Either use  as a container or simply use the  one after the other ( is also an inline element)